# An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManage

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a repository model method:-

```
public void InsertOrUpdateServer(TMSServer server, string username,long assetid)
{
  var resource = GetResourceDetials(assetid);
  if (server.ServerID == default(int))
  {
    //code goes here>>>>>>>>.......>>>
  }
  else
  {
    // Existing entity
    var auditinfo = IntiateAudit(
                      tms.AuditActions.SingleOrDefault(
                        a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "EDIT").ActionID,
                          tms.TechnologyTypes.SingleOrDefault(
                            a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "Server").AssetTypeID,
                              username, server.ServerID
                     );

    server.IT360SiteID = resource.SITEID.Value;
    tms.Entry(server).State = EntityState.Modified; // this will raise the esception         
    InsertOrUpdateAudit(auditinfo);
  }
}
```

but when this method is call i will get the folloiwng exception on :-

```
tms.Entry(server).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: An object with
>   the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The
>   ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
>
> Source Error: Line 1046:                 username, server.ServerID);
>   Line 1047:                server.IT360SiteID =
>   resource.SITEID.Value;///// Line 1048:
>   tms.Entry(server).State = EntityState.Modified; Line 1049:
>   //  tms.Entry(technologyIP).State = EntityState.Modified; Line 1050:
>   InsertOrUpdateAudit(auditinfo);

So i can not figure out what is causing this isssue , since i am only tracking one object named servev ?? can anyone advice on what is going on ?

Comment: IF tms is already tracking the object, you don't need to modifiy its state. Try removing that line.

Comment: but i do not think it is tracking it any where ..